# set /p not taking environment variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to match a batch script to do [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-save-all-windows-spotlight-lockscreen-images) tutorial automatically, for any system.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=4* delims= " %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "My Pictures"') do (set loc=%%A %%B)
set loc=%loc%\Spotlight
set /p loc=Location for images (default - "%loc%") [use %%loc%% for default]?: 
start robocopy "%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets" "%temp%\spotlight"
ren %temp%\spotlight\*.* *.jpg
robocopy "%temp%\spotlight" "%loc%"
start %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %loc%
```

However, if I try typing `%loc%\Spotlight2`, it places it in the `Desktop\%loc%\spotlight2` (desktop is the current working directory).

Is there a way to make `set /p` take environment variables?

Comment: You can't set the variable loc to %loc% and expect it to be the same contents as it previously was.  All you have to do is tell them to hit enter to use the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the usual way to enter a default is an empty input (keeps predefined varable unchanged). But there is a way to enable a variable input. Try the following and answer the question with `%windir%`

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set x=%username%
set /p "x=enter value ([ENTER] for default: "%x%") "
call set x=%x%
echo %x%
```

The trick is to expand the variable twice by using another layer of parsing (whith `call`).

Answer (score 0):

SET /P is basically just an input routine.  There is no documented way to have it do further evaluation, and I doubt one exists.

One could try to get CMD to evaluate the contents of a variable to expand any variables in the contents -- I have seem kludges to do this.  However, I don't think that is a good way to do what you want.

I think you would be better off using something easier to type, and testing for that explicitly.  For example:

```
set loc=%loc%\Spotlight
echo Enter location for images, or just press [ENTER] to use the default.
echo Default location: %loc%
set userloc=*
set /p userloc=Location? 
if not "%userloc%"=="*" set loc=%userloc%
```

Comment: So there is no way to do what I want?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't think the alternative approach suggested would be suitable for your scenario?

Comment: That does not work the way I want to, I cannot just type `%loc%\s`. It is just a more nicely formatted of the one I was using.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do what you want without default locations! It involves variable manipulation:

```
...
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set loc=%loc%\Spotlight
set default=%loc%
set /p "loc=Location [%loc%] for default: "
set out=!loc:%%loc%%=%default%!
echo %out%
...
```

Hence, typing `%loc%` replaces it with the original value of `loc`.

I tested this by typing `%loc%\s` and it performed as expected. In terms of it being the correct directory, thats to do with how you set the value of loc prior to this code.